# Option to view entire markdown source text in suggested edit review

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I recently encountered a suggested edit which replaced the display text of several links (the text in square brackets) which were using the "URL is in footnote" markdown. I couldn't see the URLs because they were in the "*n* identical lines skipped" section, so I couldn't really judge whether the edited text matches the URL.

Would it be possible to add a third button alongside the existing `rendered output` and `markdown` which would show the complete markdown (not skipping identical lines), something like `full markdown`? I can imagine other cases where this would be useful.

I know there are workarounds - using `Improve` or, in this particular case of URLs, hovering the mouse in the `rendered output` view the URL. Still, I believe it would be useful to have the option to view the markdown unabridged.